# Strange behaviour of list in R

Tags: r

I ran on a very strange behaviour. I am trying to evaluate a rather long list (Generated code).

```
list( 'Food', 100, 199, 'Food', 200, 299, 'Food', 700, 799, 'Food', 910, 919, 'Food', 2000, 2009, 'Food', 2010, 2019, 'Food', 2020, 2029, 'Food', 2030, 2039, 'Food', 2040, 2046, 'Food', 2048, 2048, 'Food', 2050, 2059, 'Food', 2060, 2063, 'Food', 2064, 2068, 'Food', 2070, 2079, 'Food', 2086, 2086, 'Food', 2087, 2087, 'Food', 2090, 2092, 'Food', 2095, 2095, 'Food', 2096, 2096, 'Food', 2097, 2097, 'Food', 2098, 2099, 'Food', 5800, 5819, 'Food', 5820, 5829, 'Food', 5890, 5899, 'Food', 7000, 7000, 'Food', 7010, 7019, 'Food', 7040, 7049, 'Food', 7213, 7213, 'Food', 2080, 2080, 'Food', 2082, 2082, 'Food', 2083, 2083, 'Food', 2084, 2084, 'Food', 2085, 2085, 'Food', 2100, 2199,  'Hlth', 2830, 2830, 'Hlth', 2831, 2831, 'Hlth', 2833, 2833, 'Hlth', 2834, 2834, 'Hlth', 2835, 2835, 'Hlth', 2836, 2836, 'Hlth', 3693, 3693, 'Hlth', 3840, 3849, 'Hlth', 3850, 3851, 'Hlth', 8000, 8099,  'Cnstr', 800, 899, 'Cnstr', 1500, 1511, 'Cnstr', 1520, 1529, 'Cnstr', 1530, 1539, 'Cnstr', 1540, 1549, 'Cnstr', 1600, 1699, 'Cnstr', 1700, 1799, 'Cnstr', 2400, 2439, 'Cnstr', 2450, 2459, 'Cnstr', 2490, 2499, 'Cnstr', 2660, 2661, 'Cnstr', 2950, 2952, 'Cnstr', 3200, 3200, 'Cnstr', 3210, 3211, 'Cnstr', 3240, 3241, 'Cnstr', 3250, 3259, 'Cnstr', 3261, 3261, 'Cnstr', 3264, 3264, 'Cnstr', 3270, 3275, 'Cnstr', 3280, 3281, 'Cnstr', 3290, 3293, 'Cnstr', 3295, 3299, 'Cnstr', 3420, 3429, 'Cnstr', 3430, 3433, 'Cnstr', 3440, 3441, 'Cnstr', 3442, 3442, 'Cnstr', 3446, 3446, 'Cnstr', 3448, 3448, 'Cnstr', 3449, 3449, 'Cnstr', 3450, 3451, 'Cnstr', 3452, 3452, 'Cnstr', 3490, 3499, 'Cnstr', 3996, 3996, 'Cnstr', 3400, 3400, 'Cnstr', 3443, 3443, 'Cnstr', 3444, 3444, 'Cnstr', 3460, 3469, 'Cnstr', 3470, 3479, 'Cnstr', 3510, 3519, 'Cnstr', 3520, 3529, 'Cnstr', 3530, 3530, 'Cnstr', 3531, 3531, 'Cnstr', 3532, 3532, 'Cnstr', 3533, 3533, 'Cnstr', 3534, 3534, 'Cnstr', 3535, 3535, 'Cnstr', 3536, 3536, 'Cnstr', 3538, 3538, 'Cnstr', 3540, 3549, 'Cnstr', 3550, 3559, 'Cnstr', 3560, 3569, 'Cnstr', 3580, 3580, 'Cnstr', 3581, 3581, 'Cnstr', 3582, 3582, 'Cnstr', 3585, 3585, 'Cnstr', 3586, 3586, 'Cnstr', 3589, 3589, 'Cnstr', 3590, 3599, 'Cnstr', 3300, 3300, 'Cnstr', 3310, 3317, 'Cnstr', 3320, 3325, 'Cnstr', 3330, 3339, 'Cnstr', 3340, 3341, 'Cnstr', 3350, 3357, 'Cnstr', 3360, 3369, 'Cnstr', 3370, 3379, 'Cnstr', 3390, 3399, 'Cnstr', 3600, 3600, 'Cnstr', 3610, 3613, 'Cnstr', 3620, 3621, 'Cnstr', 3623, 3629, 'Cnstr', 3640, 3644, 'Cnstr', 3645, 3645, 'Cnstr', 3646, 3646, 'Cnstr', 3648, 3649, 'Cnstr', 3660, 3660, 'Cnstr', 3690, 3690, 'Cnstr', 3691, 3692, 'Cnstr', 3699, 3699,  'OCM', 1300, 1300, 'OCM', 1310, 1319, 'OCM', 1320, 1329, 'OCM', 1330, 1339, 'OCM', 1370, 1379, 'OCM', 1380, 1380, 'OCM', 1381, 1381, 'OCM', 1382, 1382, 'OCM', 1389, 1389, 'OCM', 2900, 2912, 'OCM', 2990, 2999, 'OCM', 1200, 1299, 'OCM', 1000, 1009, 'OCM', 1010, 1019, 'OCM', 1020, 1029, 'OCM', 1030, 1039, 'OCM', 1040, 1049, 'OCM', 1050, 1059, 'OCM', 1060, 1069, 'OCM', 1070, 1079, 'OCM', 1080, 1089, 'OCM', 1090, 1099, 'OCM', 1100, 1119, 'OCM', 1400, 1499, 'OCM', 2800, 2809, 'OCM', 2810, 2819, 'OCM', 2820, 2829, 'OCM', 2850, 2859, 'OCM', 2860, 2869, 'OCM', 2870, 2879, 'OCM', 2890, 2899,  'Util', 4900, 4900, 'Util', 4910, 4911, 'Util', 4920, 4922, 'Util', 4923, 4923, 'Util', 4924, 4925, 'Util', 4930, 4931, 'Util', 4932, 4932, 'Util', 4939, 4939, 'Util', 4940, 4942,  'IT', 4800, 4800, 'IT', 4810, 4813, 'IT', 4820, 4822, 'IT', 4830, 4839, 'IT', 4840, 4841, 'IT', 4880, 4889, 'IT', 4890, 4890, 'IT', 4891, 4891, 'IT', 4892, 4892, 'IT', 4899, 4899, 'IT', 7370, 7372, 'IT', 7374, 7374, 'IT', 7375, 7375, 'IT', 7376, 7376, 'IT', 7377, 7377, 'IT', 7378, 7378, 'IT', 7379, 7379, 'IT', 3669, 3669, 'IT', 3670, 3679, 'IT', 3680, 3680, 'IT', 3681, 3681, 'IT', 3682, 3682, 'IT', 3683, 3683, 'IT', 3684, 3684, 'IT', 3685, 3685, 'IT', 3686, 3686, 'IT', 3687, 3687, 'IT', 3688, 3688, 'IT', 3689, 3689, 'IT', 3695, 3695, 'IT', 3810, 3810, 'IT', 7373, 7373, 'IT', 3570, 3579, 'IT', 5063, 5063, 'IT', 5734, 5734, 'IT', 5045, 5045, 'IT', 5995, 5995,  'Servs', 7020, 7021, 'Servs', 7030, 7033, 'Servs', 7200, 7200, 'Servs', 7210, 7212, 'Servs', 7214, 7214, 'Servs', 7215)
```

The interpreter cannot evaluate it. However, if I remove just one character from the last entry.

```
list( 'Food', 100, 199, 'Food', 200, 299, 'Food', 700, 799, 'Food', 910, 919, 'Food', 2000, 2009, 'Food', 2010, 2019, 'Food', 2020, 2029, 'Food', 2030, 2039, 'Food', 2040, 2046, 'Food', 2048, 2048, 'Food', 2050, 2059, 'Food', 2060, 2063, 'Food', 2064, 2068, 'Food', 2070, 2079, 'Food', 2086, 2086, 'Food', 2087, 2087, 'Food', 2090, 2092, 'Food', 2095, 2095, 'Food', 2096, 2096, 'Food', 2097, 2097, 'Food', 2098, 2099, 'Food', 5800, 5819, 'Food', 5820, 5829, 'Food', 5890, 5899, 'Food', 7000, 7000, 'Food', 7010, 7019, 'Food', 7040, 7049, 'Food', 7213, 7213, 'Food', 2080, 2080, 'Food', 2082, 2082, 'Food', 2083, 2083, 'Food', 2084, 2084, 'Food', 2085, 2085, 'Food', 2100, 2199,  'Hlth', 2830, 2830, 'Hlth', 2831, 2831, 'Hlth', 2833, 2833, 'Hlth', 2834, 2834, 'Hlth', 2835, 2835, 'Hlth', 2836, 2836, 'Hlth', 3693, 3693, 'Hlth', 3840, 3849, 'Hlth', 3850, 3851, 'Hlth', 8000, 8099,  'Cnstr', 800, 899, 'Cnstr', 1500, 1511, 'Cnstr', 1520, 1529, 'Cnstr', 1530, 1539, 'Cnstr', 1540, 1549, 'Cnstr', 1600, 1699, 'Cnstr', 1700, 1799, 'Cnstr', 2400, 2439, 'Cnstr', 2450, 2459, 'Cnstr', 2490, 2499, 'Cnstr', 2660, 2661, 'Cnstr', 2950, 2952, 'Cnstr', 3200, 3200, 'Cnstr', 3210, 3211, 'Cnstr', 3240, 3241, 'Cnstr', 3250, 3259, 'Cnstr', 3261, 3261, 'Cnstr', 3264, 3264, 'Cnstr', 3270, 3275, 'Cnstr', 3280, 3281, 'Cnstr', 3290, 3293, 'Cnstr', 3295, 3299, 'Cnstr', 3420, 3429, 'Cnstr', 3430, 3433, 'Cnstr', 3440, 3441, 'Cnstr', 3442, 3442, 'Cnstr', 3446, 3446, 'Cnstr', 3448, 3448, 'Cnstr', 3449, 3449, 'Cnstr', 3450, 3451, 'Cnstr', 3452, 3452, 'Cnstr', 3490, 3499, 'Cnstr', 3996, 3996, 'Cnstr', 3400, 3400, 'Cnstr', 3443, 3443, 'Cnstr', 3444, 3444, 'Cnstr', 3460, 3469, 'Cnstr', 3470, 3479, 'Cnstr', 3510, 3519, 'Cnstr', 3520, 3529, 'Cnstr', 3530, 3530, 'Cnstr', 3531, 3531, 'Cnstr', 3532, 3532, 'Cnstr', 3533, 3533, 'Cnstr', 3534, 3534, 'Cnstr', 3535, 3535, 'Cnstr', 3536, 3536, 'Cnstr', 3538, 3538, 'Cnstr', 3540, 3549, 'Cnstr', 3550, 3559, 'Cnstr', 3560, 3569, 'Cnstr', 3580, 3580, 'Cnstr', 3581, 3581, 'Cnstr', 3582, 3582, 'Cnstr', 3585, 3585, 'Cnstr', 3586, 3586, 'Cnstr', 3589, 3589, 'Cnstr', 3590, 3599, 'Cnstr', 3300, 3300, 'Cnstr', 3310, 3317, 'Cnstr', 3320, 3325, 'Cnstr', 3330, 3339, 'Cnstr', 3340, 3341, 'Cnstr', 3350, 3357, 'Cnstr', 3360, 3369, 'Cnstr', 3370, 3379, 'Cnstr', 3390, 3399, 'Cnstr', 3600, 3600, 'Cnstr', 3610, 3613, 'Cnstr', 3620, 3621, 'Cnstr', 3623, 3629, 'Cnstr', 3640, 3644, 'Cnstr', 3645, 3645, 'Cnstr', 3646, 3646, 'Cnstr', 3648, 3649, 'Cnstr', 3660, 3660, 'Cnstr', 3690, 3690, 'Cnstr', 3691, 3692, 'Cnstr', 3699, 3699,  'OCM', 1300, 1300, 'OCM', 1310, 1319, 'OCM', 1320, 1329, 'OCM', 1330, 1339, 'OCM', 1370, 1379, 'OCM', 1380, 1380, 'OCM', 1381, 1381, 'OCM', 1382, 1382, 'OCM', 1389, 1389, 'OCM', 2900, 2912, 'OCM', 2990, 2999, 'OCM', 1200, 1299, 'OCM', 1000, 1009, 'OCM', 1010, 1019, 'OCM', 1020, 1029, 'OCM', 1030, 1039, 'OCM', 1040, 1049, 'OCM', 1050, 1059, 'OCM', 1060, 1069, 'OCM', 1070, 1079, 'OCM', 1080, 1089, 'OCM', 1090, 1099, 'OCM', 1100, 1119, 'OCM', 1400, 1499, 'OCM', 2800, 2809, 'OCM', 2810, 2819, 'OCM', 2820, 2829, 'OCM', 2850, 2859, 'OCM', 2860, 2869, 'OCM', 2870, 2879, 'OCM', 2890, 2899,  'Util', 4900, 4900, 'Util', 4910, 4911, 'Util', 4920, 4922, 'Util', 4923, 4923, 'Util', 4924, 4925, 'Util', 4930, 4931, 'Util', 4932, 4932, 'Util', 4939, 4939, 'Util', 4940, 4942,  'IT', 4800, 4800, 'IT', 4810, 4813, 'IT', 4820, 4822, 'IT', 4830, 4839, 'IT', 4840, 4841, 'IT', 4880, 4889, 'IT', 4890, 4890, 'IT', 4891, 4891, 'IT', 4892, 4892, 'IT', 4899, 4899, 'IT', 7370, 7372, 'IT', 7374, 7374, 'IT', 7375, 7375, 'IT', 7376, 7376, 'IT', 7377, 7377, 'IT', 7378, 7378, 'IT', 7379, 7379, 'IT', 3669, 3669, 'IT', 3670, 3679, 'IT', 3680, 3680, 'IT', 3681, 3681, 'IT', 3682, 3682, 'IT', 3683, 3683, 'IT', 3684, 3684, 'IT', 3685, 3685, 'IT', 3686, 3686, 'IT', 3687, 3687, 'IT', 3688, 3688, 'IT', 3689, 3689, 'IT', 3695, 3695, 'IT', 3810, 3810, 'IT', 7373, 7373, 'IT', 3570, 3579, 'IT', 5063, 5063, 'IT', 5734, 5734, 'IT', 5045, 5045, 'IT', 5995, 5995,  'Servs', 7020, 7021, 'Servs', 7030, 7033, 'Servs', 7200, 7200, 'Servs', 7210, 7212, 'Servs', 7214, 7214, 'Servs', 721)
```

it works!

Any ideas? The real list is actually twice as long as this one.
I am running R 3.1.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Edit:

When the first list is pasted into a file and run from the interpreter using source() everything seems to behave appropriatly. The strange behaviour seems to occur only when pasting the code in the interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably hitting the console character limit.  Just separate the list into multiple lines at some of the comma delimiters.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there was a limit. I just piped the generated code into a file and sourced it. Works like a charm now.